# File Not receiving in Slack RTM Driver with Laravel?

Tags: php, slack-api, laravel-5.5

I'm currently Trying to make Slack Bot. for this purpose I'm using https://botman.io its wrapper of Laravel.5. 
The issue is its responding for any text which mentioned in Here..
here is my working code

```
$botman->hears('hi', function ($bot) {
   $bot->typesAndWaits(2);
   $bot->reply('Hello!');
});

$botman->hears('ok', function ($bot) {
    $bot->typesAndWaits(2);
    $bot->reply('anything else!');
});
```

Now its working fine but when I try to use recieved any file its not responding even WHEN i Try to receive any image its not responding 
here is my code

```
$botman->receivesImages(function($bot, $images) {

foreach ($images as $image) {

    $url = $image->getUrl(); // The direct url
    $title = $image->getTitle(); // The title, if available
    $payload = $image->getPayload(); // The original payload
 }

  $bot->reply('image');
});

$botman->receivesFiles(function($bot, $files) {

   foreach ($files as $file) {

      $url = $file->getUrl(); // The direct url
      $payload = $file->getPayload(); // The original payload
    }
    $bot->reply('rec!');
});
```

Also I have fallback method when I try to use fallback and try to upload ay file its always fallback 
here is all packages which is using
[Botman](https://github.com/botman/botman) 
[driver-slack](https://github.com/botman/driver-slack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems a package problem I raise an issue on github and they release new version which fixed that problem